# Trouble allocating array of structs

Tags: c

My code segfaults whenever I try to access the structs data members. This has to be because it is not properly allocated. I do not know why this isn't working. The struct looks like it is defined correctly. The malloc looks like it is set up correctly. I use correct format to access the data. However it just segfaults whenever I try to access anything.

```
struct fracBlock {
  struct fracBlock *next ;
  fraction frac ;
} ;

static struct fracBlock *fbp ;

void init_heap(void){ fbp = NULL ; }

fraction *new_frac(void){
  struct fracBlock **tempBlock ;
  struct fracBlock *prev ;
  struct fracBlock *curr ;
  fraction *tempFrac ;
  fraction testFrac ;
  int i ;
//if free list is empty malloc 10 blocks
  if ( fbp == NULL ){
    tempBlock = ( struct fracBlock** )malloc(10*sizeof(struct fracBlock)) ;

  //if no more space left
  if ( tempBlock == NULL ) {
    printf( "\nError: No more memory space left for allocation!\n" ) ;
    exit(1) ;
  }

  tempBlock[0]->next = tempBlock[1] ;
  tempBlock[1]->next = tempBlock[2] ;
  tempBlock[2]->next = tempBlock[3] ;
  tempBlock[3]->next = tempBlock[4] ;
  tempBlock[4]->next = tempBlock[5] ;
  tempBlock[5]->next = tempBlock[6] ;
  tempBlock[6]->next = tempBlock[7] ;
  tempBlock[7]->next = tempBlock[8] ;
  tempBlock[8]->next = NULL ;
  *tempFrac = tempBlock[9]->frac ;

  return tempFrac ;
}
```

Comment: Why do you use a double pointer?

Comment: can you edit your code?  there's a missing closing '}' somewhere.

Comment: in addition to the double pointer error, `*tempFrac = tempBlock[9]->frac ;` is wrong because `tempFract` is uninitialized.

Comment: Step 1: Fix all compiler warnings....

Answer (score 2):

You have a number serious bugs in the posted code.

1) There is missing a `}`

2) `tempfrac` is an **uninitialized** pointer but you do `*tempfrac = ...` That is undefined behavior so any thing may happen. A crash is likely. Maybe you forgot to `malloc` memory like `tempfrac = malloc(sizeof *tempfrac);`

3) Even if `tempfrac` is assigned using `malloc` the line `*tempFrac = tempBlock[9]->frac ;` is still wrong because `frac` in block 9 is also uninitialized. The code makes no sense.. it tries to return (a pointer to) an uninitialized value.

4) The use of double pointer is just wrong. The code should be more like:

```
  struct fracBlock *tempBlock ;  // Single *

  if ( fbp == NULL ){
    tempBlock = malloc(10*sizeof *tempBlock) ;

    //if no more space left
    if ( tempBlock == NULL ) {
      printf( "\nError: No more memory space left for allocation!\n" ) ;
      exit(1) ;
    }

    tempBlock[0].next = tempBlock + 1; // or tempBlock[0].next = &tempBlock[1];
    tempBlock[1].next = tempBlock + 2;
    ...
```

5) You never update `fbp` In other words, the `malloc` you do is into a pointer that goes out of scope when the function completes. So you have a memory leak. Most likely you shouldn't use a local variable `tempBlock` but instead operate directly on `fbp`. Like:

```
  if ( fbp == NULL ){
    fbp = malloc(10*sizeof *fbp) ;

    //if no more space left
    if ( fbp == NULL ) {
      printf( "\nError: No more memory space left for allocation!\n" ) ;
      exit(1) ;
    }

    fbp[0].next = fbp + 1;
    fbp[1].next = fbp + 2;
    ...
```

That said, notice that global variables are nearly always a bad thing. Avoid them.

Answer (score 0):

I think these are the problems, but someone please call me out if I made a mistake.

If I have an integer array, I allocate it in this manner:

```
int * x ; // Array of length 3
x = ( int * ) malloc( 3 * sizeof( int ) ) ;
```

I cast x as `int *` because malloc will return an address in the heap, and I want that address to be interpreted as a pointer to an integer. However, I use `int` inside the malloc call since I want to allocate enough space for 3 `int` types.

So, you'll want to use `sizeof( struct fracBlock * )` instead of `sizeof( struct fracBlock )` for that reason. You'll also need to allocate space for each of the elements of that array with `malloc` calls. This is because each element of the array is a pointer, and when you allocate it, it isn't *necessarily* pointing to any space you've been allocated yet.

Also, I think you need to allocate space for tempFrac with another malloc call. You dereference the pointer when assigning it a value, but heap space has not been allocated, leading to a segfault since you do not *necessarily* have permission to write to that memory.

The real solution though... garbage collection.

Comment: 1) In C you do not need to cast the value returned by `malloc`. A void pointer can be assigned to any other pointer. In C most programmers recommend that you do **not** make the cast. So the recommended approach is `x = malloc(3 * sizeof *x);`. 2) I do not understand this part: "The real solution though... garbage collection." There is no garbage collection in C. And even if there were, how would garbage collection help?

Comment: 1) I recognize what you're saying, and you're right, you don't NEED to do the cast. I didn't realize it was bad practice, though. Not sure why that would be the case. If anything, it seems like you'd be reiterating what the type of the variable is later in the code. 2) It was a joke. If you use a language that automates your memory management, you don't have any of these problems. "Garbage collection" was probably not the best technical term to use though since that would only help you with ```free``` calls as far as I understand.